# python changing location using for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, location

I want to change location by putting command but got trouble in for loop

All I want is put R R R U D D and get (3,4) location

here is my code

x,y = first start point
N= size of map

```
N=5
x,y = 1,1
```

I define left(-1,0), right(1,0), upper(0,-1), down(0,1)

```
def L(x,y):
    if x>1 and x<N and y>1 and y<N:
        x=x
        y=y-1
        return(x,y)
    else:
        return(x,y)
def R(x,y):
    if x<N and y<N:
        x=x
        y=y+1
        return(x,y)
    else:
        return(x,y)
def U(x,y):
    if x>1 and x<N and y>1 and y<N:
        x=x-1
        y=y
        return(x,y)
    else:
        return(x,y)
def D(x,y):
    if x<N and y<N:
        x=x+1
        y=y
        return(x,y)
    else:
        return(x,y)
```

input command

```
move_type=L(x,y),R(x,y),U(x,y),D(x,y)


num = [*map(int, input().split())]
```

put num [1 1]

change location - this is the point where I got trouble

```
for i in num:
    x,y = move_type[i]
    print(x,y)
```

**result come like this

```
1 2
1 2
```

I expect (1,2)
(1,3)

what's wrong with my code
help me plz**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Method like that

```
num = [*map(int, input().split())]
x, y = num

# move_type=L(x,y),R(x,y),U(x,y),D(x,y) 
# above tuple has the return value of function because you call them with the x and y as 1.


move_type = L, R, U, D  # But here I only provide the function name to 
                        # tuple and later I execute them with the new x and y values

for i in num:
    x, y = move_type[i](x, y) # calling the function with the new value of x and y
    print(x, y)
```

One suggestion change your all functions

```
def L(x, y):
    if x > 1 and x < N and y > 1 and y < N: # if this if execute then the x and y modify and return at the end
        x = x
        y = y-1

    # but if if not execute the x and y values return to the same x and y values
    return (x, y) # this will return the x, y

 
def R(x, y):
    if x < N and y < N:
        x = x
        y = y+1
    return (x, y)


def U(x, y):
    if x > 1 and x < N and y > 1 and y < N:
        x = x-1
        y = y
    return (x, y)


def D(x, y):
    if x < N and y < N:
        x = x+1
        y = y
    return (x, y)
```

Comment: @김도영 Check  updates too

Comment: I checked your updates
What's good about changing like this?

Comment: can I ask 1 more Question?
Is there a way to input R R R U D D directly 
for i in num:
    x,y = move_type[i](x,y)
    print(x,y)
in this part?

Comment: Yeah there is a way

Comment: I will update it in a minute